# Find the minimum of the maximum of certain function in python?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimum, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a peice of mathematica code that finds the minimum of maximum of function in two variables. Lets say the function is (specific not important):

```
F[x1_,y1_,x2_,y2_,x_,y_] := x1**2 + y1**2 + x2**2 + y2**2 + a*x**2 + b*y**2
```

Right now i am finding the required minima of maxima of `F[x,y]` in mathematica as:

```
Minimize[Max[F[x1,y1,0,0,x,y],F[0,0,x2,y2,A-x,B-y]],{x,y}]
```

where A and B are some constants.
Since, I have a huge datasets for which this function (minima) has to be computed and loading datasets in mathematica causes memory problem. So, I am trying to write the same code in python and I am stuck in this minimization part.Basically we have to find x and y for minima of maxima of two F[].

Right now the code looks like this:

```
 def f(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y):
       return something
     for i in range(len(data)):
       A = calculate constant A
       B = calculate cosntant B
       xmin,ymin = min(max(f(x1,y1,x,y),f(x2,y2,x,y))) // here i tried using scipy.optimize.min
```

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should get you running:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y):
    return something

def objective_f(A, B, x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y):
    return max([f(x1, y1 ,0 ,0 ,x ,y), f(0, 0, x2, y2, A-x, B-y)])


for d in range(len(data)):
    A = calculate constant A
    B = calculate cosntant B
    x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2 = d
    # you have to set A, B, x1, y1, x2, y2 as 'default' args separately
    rex = minimize(objective_f, args=(A, B, x1, y1, x2, y2), method="CG", x0=np.zeros((2, )))
    x_min, y_min = res.x
```

Docs for `optimize` are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). Use them to set the appropriate parameters. I have provided only sensible defaults. I'm not sure whether `x1, y1, x2, y2` need to be optimized too. Are they constants? This can be easily adjusted if needed, just remove them from args and `res.x` will output all 6 variables.